# height:100%でのoverflow: scrollがスマホでうまく行きません

Tags: css, mobile

cssで下記のようにサブのメニューを設定したところ、スマートフォンではサブメニューの途中でスクロールが止まり、
本体部分をスクロールし終わるまで、サブの残りがスクロールできません。
どのように対策すれば良いでしょうか？

```
#submenu{
  height:100%;
  width: 80%;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: HTML部分はありますか？再現ができない...

Answer (score 1):

何かボタンをおした時メニューが開き、そのメニューが画面縦いっぱいに表示されるというイメージでしょうか？
メニューが開いている間、本体部分のスクロールを止めてもいいのであれば、そうしてみてはどうでしょうか。

```
body.locked{
　overflow-y: hidden;
}
/* メニューが開いている時このclassをbodyにつける */
#submenu{
  height:100%;
  width: 80%;
  overflow:auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}
```